# Apache HTTP: Define environment variable as a "random" number

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to define an environment variable as a random number, say like between 1 and 10 in my `httpd.conf`. Is this possible?

I'm using `mod_proxy_html` and I want to rewrite some URLs to simulate a CDN, so I would need to define something like this:

```
ProxyHTMLURLMap /myapp http://cdn${RAND_DIGIT|1}.localhost/myapp [V]
```

Later on, my hosts file will be like this:

```
127.0.0.1       cdn1.localhost
127.0.0.1       cdn2.localhost
127.0.0.1       cdn3.localhost
127.0.0.1       cdn4.localhost
127.0.0.1       cdn5.localhost
```

Thanks

--

Clarification: I'm using this technique for static resources such as javascript, css, etc. So the session affinity problem does not arise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) Apache module.

With random numbers will not work session.

Comment: Check my edit/clarification

Answer (score 0):

The variable will only be read on start-up, so it will stay going to the same CDN until Apache restarts.

You could look at some form of round-robin DNS, but that would require setting up a local DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rnd` MapType with [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) in mod_rewite.

Comment: I can't seem to use the `${servers:dynamic}` syntax outside of Rewrite Rules

Comment: @MiguelPing: It works in mod_rewrite.